# How to get special character records using NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

In the following table, I want to get the only Dallas records to target, 
For that which processors do I need to use. of course, it is a basic question but lot clarification based on this question.

id   city    country   temp   date

101  Dallas  US        10     10/02

102  Texas   US        20     11/02

103  Dallas   US        30     12/02

104  Florida US        40     13/02

105  Dallas  US        10     14/02

106  Vegas   US        20     15/02

Thank you.

Comment: please add more details where this table is located. is it a relationsl database? what have you tried to achieve your goal?

Comment: Oracle to PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Use [QueryRecord](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/121794/running-sql-on-flowfiles-using-queryrecord-process.html) processor and add new property to the processor as

```
select * from flowfile where city="Dallas"
```

Output from QueryRecord processor will have only the **`Dallas`** records in it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.. in this case, querydatabasetable is not required?

Comment: @Kum, You still need to use `QueryDatabaseTable` pull data from source and to filter out the required data use `QueryRecord` processor.